# How to give effect like throwing a ball in a Bucket?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to Cocos2d and hence not aware of most of the classes and also the functions. In my application, I want to implement a module like touching and dragging the ball in a direction of a barrel will pass the ball and will put the ball in the barrel. I am able to pass the ball in the direction but then it just would go out of the screen following the coordinates(x.y).

```
    - (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
    {
        // Choose one of the touches to work with
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

        //  Determine offset of location to projectile
        int offX = location.x - ball.position.x;
        int offY = location.y - ball.position.y;

        // Bail out if we are shooting down or backwards
        if (offX <= 0)
            return;

        // Determine where we wish to shoot the projectile to
        int realX = winSize.width + (ball.contentSize.height/2);
        float ratio = (float) offY / (float) offX;
        int realY = (realX * ratio) + ball.position.y;
        CGPoint realDest = ccp(realX, realY);

        if(realX>=320)
            realX = 320;
        if(realY>=480)
            realY = 480;
        CGPoint realDest = ccp(realX, realY);

        int good = goodBarrel.position.x;
        int bad = badBarrel.position.x;

        int destY = realDest.x;
        if(destY<=good)
            destY = good;

        if(destY>=bad)
            destY = bad;

        realDest.x = destY+10;

        // Determine the length of how far we're shooting
        int offRealX = realX - ball.position.x;
        int offRealY = realY - ball.position.y;
        float length = sqrtf((offRealX*offRealX)+(offRealY*offRealY));
        float velocity = 480/1; // 480pixels/1sec
        float realMoveDuration = length/velocity;

        // Move projectile to actual endpoint
        [ball runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                               [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:realMoveDuration position:realDest],
                               [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)],
                               nil]];                         
}
```

I need to do something like it will get the idea of barrels position and finding the top of the barrel and will put the ball in the center of the barrel and also while moving the ball,the size of the ball gets reduced to give effect of throwing the ball to a distant place. GoodBarrel and BadBarrel are the two barrels I have put in the opposite of ball to put the ball in the same. Is there any function or method I can work on?

Comment: Take a look at this post, [Best method for paper toss game](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/21966#post-122109).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately after the [ball runAction: .... ]; line, you can run another action on the same object, simultaneously. Add a

```
[ball runAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:realMoveDuration scale:0.4f];
```

both actions will complete at the same time, providing the 'illusion' of distance you are seeking to create.

Comment: I am able to reduce the size with the same code. But what I want to do is I need to give effect like throwing in a bucket. What happens is that when my moving object detects the another object it is removed.While I need effect like throwing in a bucket. Like moving up for some pixels and and pushing back to give effect. While my object gets hidden in backside of the bucket.

Comment: ah, i mis-understood your question. You meant 'the flying object bounces on back wall, and then drops inside the bucket' ?   or is it the bucket itself you want to shake ? Either would be very hard to fake with a 2D engine, without causing some kind of cognitive disconnect for the user.

Comment: I could not understand your statement "cognitive disconnect for the user". Also I need to give effect like bouncing ball in a bucket. Like that happens in one app called paper toss,if you have heard.

Comment: errr ... cognitive disconnect is when you see something, and there is something 'wrong' with what you are seeing, but cant necessarily point your finger to it. Take the 'tossed object'. If you toss in a straight line, you dont see the effect of 'gravity', so you have to make the trajectory some kind of curve to fake that. The paper ball bounces on the far-wall of the bucket, when it is dropping you have to make certain that is has lower Z order than the front side of the bucket, etc etc etc .... Lots of attention to pay to minute details if you attempt this with a 2D model.

Comment: Sorry for late reply YvesLeBorg, I went through your explanation. It was quite good but I am still blank with the point whether I can use such a functionality with Cocos2d or should I move further with Cocos3d? I really am blank as far as this matter is concerned..!!

Comment: Unfortunately, i have zilch experience with cocos3D, unclear about its features. Maybe toss the questions on the cocos2d-iphone.org forums. Also read about cocos3D here : http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/

Answer (score 0):

You can use collision detection, or in other words check to see if the CGRect of ball and barrel intersect

```
- (void)collisionDetection:(ccTime)dt{
CGRect ballRect = CGRectMake(
                                   ball.position.x, 
                                   ball.position.y, 
                                   10, 
                                   10);


    CGRect barrelRect = CGRectMake(
                                   barrel.position.x, 
                                   barrel.position.y, 
                                   50, 
                                   10);

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ballRect, barrelRect)) 
 {
        // Run Animation of Ball Dropping in the Barrel

        [self removeChild:ball cleanup: YES];


}
}
```

hope this is what you need.

Comment: so this is the code to put the ball inside the barrel? also how can i reduce the size of the ball while it is moving like smaller and smaller and finally disappear? any clue?

Comment: you can call it in the touchesEnded method itself wen the ball starts moving in the collisionDetection method add this line '[ball setScale:0.5];' this is not tested..but should work

Comment: I am doing so but when that method is called,(CGRectIntersectsRect(ballRect, barrelRect)) condition is never true and hence it never goes into this condition loop.

Comment: Also '[ball setScale:0.5];' will reduce the size of the ball once but I need effect like going far will reduce size one by one scale.

Comment: try this 'CCFiniteTimeAction *reduceSize = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.1f scale:0.5];' and about the condition.. it should be true at some point print the x and y positions of the ball n barrel to verify

Comment: I did but in vain. Okay let me try this one. will come back to you then.

Comment: CCFiniteTimeAction *reduceSize = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.1f scale:0.5]; given SIGABRT and crashes giving message CCScaleTo may not respond to actionWithDuration & actionWithDuration not found(return type defaults to 'id')